# Como iterar sobre dos dataframes iguales y realizar funciones iguales sobre ellos?

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for

Estoy operando con dos dataframes de igual columnas y filas:

[DATAFRAME1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq8X7.png)

[DATAFRAME2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqeQF.png)

En un principio comencé operando sobre uno solo, aplicando funciones y asignándolas a variables, por ejemplo:

```
#GET INFORMATION
datos = pd.DataFrame()
datos2 = pd.DataFrame()
   
for a, a2 in zip(portafolio, portafolio2):
datos[a['ticker']] = wb.DataReader(a['ticker'], data_source='yahoo', 
                                       start='2020-01-01')['Adj Close']
datos2[a2['ticker']] = wb.DataReader(a2['ticker'], data_source='yahoo', 
                                       start='2020-01-01')['Adj Close']

#Analizamos correlacion (lo ideal es que en general los activos tengan una baja correlacion)
correlacion = datos.corr()
    
retornos = datos.pct_change().dropna()
q1_retornos = retornos.mean()*360
q1_covarianza = retornos.cov()*360
```

Me gustaría poder realizar las mismas operaciones no solo al dataframe datos, si no también a datos2 sin tener que repetir el bloque de código y asignar obviamente a variables distintas (retornos & retornosdatos2, etc). Se me ocurre algo como

```
for i in range(0, len(datos.columns)):
   for j in range(0, len(datos2.columns)):
```

pero luego no se me ocurre como asignar las operaciones a distintas variables diferenciandos las calculadas sobre datos y sobre datos2.
Cualquier ayuda se agradece

Comment: Si quieres aplicar el mismo código a distintos objetos, colocas el código dentro de una función que reciba el objeto como parámetro.

Comment: En vez de distintas variables, usa distintos elementos de una lista. Por ejemplo `retornos[0]` y `retornos[1]` tendría los resultados respectivos de cada dataframe